# Implementation of hook_file_default_displays() {media module} makes it impossible to export image display settings via features

Tags: media, files

This is a issue I am dealing with for days.
It looks like is related to: https://drupal.org/node/1702700

I've created a feature relying on media, file_entity and media_youtube, vimeo... whose main purpose is to embed youtube, vimeo videos etc.

I've correctly set up the file_entity displays weights: 
Structure » File types » Video » Manage file display
so that the thumbnails shows ok

```
    e.g 
    "Large filetype icon"   weight: 50 
    "Youtube Image Preview" weight: -40.
    {GOOD}
```

[image]

```
After complete feature export,
"Large filetype icon" weight: 0 
"Youtube Image Preview" is set 2.
{WRONG}
```

I even edited manually the feature's .info and default_displays.inc file with no luck.

Secondly, there are also feature overrides unable to revert.
It looks like somethings alters the file display weights.

Comment: This is the issue: https://drupal.org/node/1858370
No progress currently. I have the same problem. Will look more in to this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems comes from the heart of Media module which programatically add default overrides.

I have managed to solve the problem in 2 steps:
(1) Sunk the Media Icon to the bottom

apply a patch to Media module:

```
--- sites/all/modules/contributed/media/media.module
+++ sites/all/modules/contributed/media/media.module
@@ -1082,7 +1082,7 @@
   $file_display = new stdClass();
   $file_display->api_version = 1;
   $file_display->name = 'video__preview__file_field_media_large_icon';
-  $file_display->weight = 0;
+  $file_display->weight = 50;
   $file_display->status = TRUE;
   $file_display->settings = '';
   $file_displays['video__preview__file_field_media_large_icon'] = $file_display;
@@ -1093,7 +1093,7 @@
   $file_display = new stdClass();
   $file_display->api_version = 1;
   $file_display->name = 'audio__preview__file_field_media_large_icon';
-  $file_display->weight = 0;
+  $file_display->weight = 50;
   $file_display->status = TRUE;
   $file_display->settings = '';
   $file_displays['audio__preview__file_field_media_large_icon'] = $file_display;
@@ -1104,7 +1104,7 @@
   $file_display = new stdClass();
   $file_display->api_version = 1;
   $file_display->name = 'document__preview__file_field_media_large_icon';
-  $file_display->weight = 0;
+  $file_display->weight = 50;
   $file_display->status = TRUE;
   $file_display->settings = '';
   $file_displays['document__preview__file_field_media_large_icon'] = $file_display;
```

(2) I exported my feature but manually edited the File Display like this:

YOURFEATURE.features.field.inc

For Default the order is

```
Vimeo 
Vimeo Preview 
Youtube 
Youtube Preview
```

For Preview the order is

```
Vimeo Preview 
Vimeo 
Youtube Preview
Youtube
```